# How to run VS 2010 Local IIS in 32 bit mode

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7.5

I have referenced some 32 bit and some 64 bit DLL in my ASP.NET MVC 3 project.

The projects compile but I get runtime errors.

It's because I am running the web project as 64 bit.

How do I "enable 32 bit" in my local IIS (just how I can do it in IIS 7.5 Pro)?

I am using .NET 4.0

The error I get is:

> Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {A6775dfd2-1dfF-421C-A187-4D55F4DDFBFF} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: See if this helps you: http://serverfault.com/questions/98257/need-to-run-an-iis-website-in-32bit-mode-on-a-64bit-windows-server

Comment: didn't help. any other suggestion pelase

Comment: What's the error? Is it definitely as a consequence of 64bit IIS and not something else?

Comment: Retrieving the COM class factory for component failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered

Answer (score 4):

If you don't require the 64 bit component (not sure what is running there or if this can be excluded as you simply wanted to know how to run in 32 bit more)

http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/201/32-bit-mode-worker-processes/

You can set it at the server level via:
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.enable32BitAppOnWin64:true

Or set your particular app pool (more recommended imho) you can try the following. Sorry the page this came from is no longer seemingly active and only googles caches is showing it now:

> Force IIS to create a 32-bit app pool worker process
>
> If your application is running as a web app, meaning it is running in
>   an IIS app pool worker process, you’ll want that worker process
>   (w3wp.exe) to be a 32-bit process.  That can be specified in the
>   advanced settings of the app pool:
>
> Select the app pool for your web app. Click Advanced Settings… under
>   Edit Application Pool on the right. Change the value of Enable 32-Bit
>   Applications under (General) to True.
>
> Note that the word “Enable” in the setting doesn’t mean “allow” as in
>   “allow either 32- or 64-bit applications.”  It actually means “force”
>   as in “force the worker process to run in 32-bit mode so that 32-bit
>   applications are supported.”  This means that the app pool worker
>   process will always be launched as a 32-bit process when this setting
>   has a value of True.  Setting it to False will launch a 64-bit app
>   pool worker process.
>
> Note that when an app pool worker process is started, it shows up in
>   the Image Name column on the Processes tab in Task Manager as
>   w3wp.exe.  When the Enable 32-Bit Applications setting has a value of
>   True, it will be listed as w3wp.exe *32.

Answer (score 2):

IIS Express 7.5 (as used by Visual Studio 2010 if you install it) is 32 bit only:

> http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/1265/iis-75-express-readme/

To quote:

> Both 32-bit and 64-bit systems are supported, **however only a 32-bit build of IIS 7.5 Express exists.**

So I can't imagine that your problems would be related to the usual 32bit / 64bit pool mode issues that can arise if all of your DLL's are 32bit.

However if you're trying to load a 64 bit COM DLL then this will fail; 64 binaries can't be loaded into a 32 bit process and vice versa.

Another gotcha is **forgetting to tick the `Use IIS Express` checkbox** when choosing which web server to debug with:

[image]

If you don't tick that checkbox then you'll run your site in a child application in the *DefaultWebSite* on the version of IIS7 that ships with Windows.

The *DefaultWebSite* runs in the *DefaultAppPool*, which in 64 bit versions of Windows runs as a 64 bit process. So you need to change the *DefaultAppPool* to run as 32 bit if you want to use this instead and consume 32 bit binaries.

You need to do this using IIS7's MMC snap-in or by running the `appcmd.exe` tool from the command line.

Comment: what do you recommend? it works in x86 windows app but not in x64 asp.net

Comment: You need to tell us much more about these COM DLL's, how they were built etc. Please add that to the question.

Comment: i think iv mentioned that it was a com dll and i used regsvr32.exe to register it. it worked in windows console application. i referenced in web project asp.net type, but it failed. try referencing any com dll, register it and you will get same problem

Comment: But you're not telling us if it's a COM component written using managed code (C#, VB.NET etc) or unmanaged code (VB6, C++ etc). There are many ways to build a COM component. Is this component 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: How did you reference it in Visual Studio? Add References -> COM Tab ?

Comment: Just updated my answer. 1. Are you sure you're running the app in VS on IIS Express and not the regular IIS web server - a common mistake. 2. Can you find your COM component in the Add References -> COM Tab? If you can't then it's not been registered properly.

Comment: Also you say you "I have referenced some 32 bit and some 64 bit DLL" so are you saying you have both a 32 bit and a 64 bit DLL - as per my answer, you can't mix 32 bit and 64 bit binaries and processes.?

Comment: can't find it in COM tab.  it's an x86 COM dll.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11610/discussion-between-kev-and-knowledgeseeker)

Answer (score 0):

Set your compile target to x86 instead of AnyCPU or x64. Your dll will always run in 32-bit without you needing to mess with the IIS server settings.