# .net Framework Error (HRESULT 0x8007000B)

Tags: c#, .net, x86, 64-bit

I have a C# application which was written on a 32bit windows XP machine with Visual Studio 2005. The application runs fine on Windows XP machines, however when I try to run it on a 64bit Windows 7 professional machine, I get the following dialog-box on start up:

[image]

Here is the full text from the details.

```
  See the end of this message for details on invoking 
just-in-time (JIT) debugging instead of this dialog box.

************** Exception Text **************
System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
   at ICSNeoCSharp.IcsNeoDll.icsneoTxMessages(Int32 hObject, IcsSpyMessage& pMsg, Int32 lNetworkID, Int32 lNumMessages)
   at ICSNeoCSharp.FormDTCApplication.transmitFlowControl(Int32 myArbID) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Adam Stuff ThinkPad\DTC Checker FINAL\frmDTCApp.cs:line 1750
   at ICSNeoCSharp.FormDTCApplication.flowControlTimer_Tick(Object sender, EventArgs e) in C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Desktop\Adam Stuff ThinkPad\DTC Checker FINAL\frmDTCApp.cs:line 5166
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.OnTick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Timer.TimerNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
   at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)


************** Loaded Assemblies **************
mscorlib
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5472 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll
----------------------------------------
DTC Checker V1.0
    Assembly Version: 1.0.4960.25549
    Win32 Version: 1.0.4960.25549
    CodeBase: file:///C:/DTC%20Checker%20V1.0%20R3/DTC%20Checker%20V1.0%20R3.exe
----------------------------------------
System.Windows.Forms
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5468 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Windows.Forms/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.Windows.Forms.dll
----------------------------------------
System
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System/2.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089/System.dll
----------------------------------------
System.Drawing
    Assembly Version: 2.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 2.0.50727.5467 (Win7SP1GDR.050727-5400)
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC_MSIL/System.Drawing/2.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a/System.Drawing.dll
----------------------------------------
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel
    Assembly Version: 12.0.0.0
    Win32 Version: 12.0.6600.1000
    CodeBase: file:///C:/Windows/assembly/GAC/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel/12.0.0.0__71e9bce111e9429c/Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll
----------------------------------------

************** JIT Debugging **************
To enable just-in-time (JIT) debugging, the .config file for this
application or computer (machine.config) must have the
jitDebugging value set in the system.windows.forms section.
The application must also be compiled with debugging
enabled.

For example:

<configuration>
    <system.windows.forms jitDebugging="true" />
</configuration>

When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box.
```

Has anyone else encountered this error and succeeded in solving it?

Comment: are you running the exe or solution in x64 ?

Comment: exe. I do not have visual studio on the Windows 7 machine.

Comment: Have you created your exe for x64 Computers

Comment: I am building for any cpu

Comment: I tried building for 64 specifically but that did not work.

Comment: again compile your code : Project Properties -> Compile -> Advanced Compile Options button  => Then you can choose the Target CPU in a combo box.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

While your main app might be built for AnyCPU are you sure all the assemblies are AnyCPU? Do you have any native assemblies or assemblies that contain native code? Are they built against x86?

file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework64/v2.0.50727/mscorlib.dll

This tells me that the app is running as an x64 process but it would appear that there is some assembly that isn't AnyCPU or x64 which is likely the cause of the BadImageFormatException.

One thing you can try is to run the application from a 32-bit command prompt (c:\windows\SysWow64\cmd.exe) to force it to be a 32-bit process and see if that works. If that works then there is definitely some assembly that is not AnyCPU.

Comment: I tried running it in the Command Promt but this did not work. I think you are on to something with an assembly not working in 64 bit. Is there anyway I can run a 32 bit assembly file in 64 bit?

Answer (score 9):

**Project Properties -> Build -> Platform target -> x86** may solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

One of the most common mistake is we forgot to change the test program and wrapper program to the correct platform. See the below image

[image]

(in the top bar it is showing the platform is x64 but you need to make sure if it is really exists in the 2nd image ...)

[image]

Make sure you have right configuration on the Configuration Manager...if your config do not match with the actual config of your c++ dll it will give BadImageFormatException.

*I learned from the mistake after searching a lot ... and finally got this*

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had the 0x8007000B error because the app was running in 32 bit, on my 64 windows 7. I solved it by going in windows/syswov64 folder changing the MSVCR110.dll version 64 bit with the MSVCR110.dll version 32 bit.

(Just don't forget to put back the 64 dll after. Each time you need to run your 32 bit app, just move the dll 32 on it).

You could find the dll versions [here](http://fr.dll-files.com/msvcr110.dll.html) (Unzip it before pasting into the syswov64 folder).

Answer (score 1):

From my experience the cause of that error is the .Net Framework Version

Check your .Net Framework version and update and also
check the .Net version of your application.

Answer (score 1):

The fix for me was to change the Application Pool in IIS.  Open the application pool properties and go to Advanced Settings...  Then change "Enable 32-bit Applications" to True.  The default is False for a new one.  The code part was set to "Any CPU" although I have fixed issues in the past by setting the CPU to x86.

Answer (score 1):

I had to combine solutions from 2-3 different answers to resolve the same error. The reason is, the final setup had dlls from both x86 and x64 platforms(in separate folders for separate exes).

1) I set the platform target of my main app as 64 bit and left configuration settings as it is and built it:
[image]

2) I set the Target platform of my Deployment project as x64.

3) The dlls were getting mixed between the folders so i checked source path of all dlls in the File Types Editor one by one and replaced them according to their architectures.

4) Finally built the deployment project with following configuration settings:
[image]

The above mentioned combination is the only one that worked.

Answer (score 0):

My issue was solved by compiling with 32 bit as Wix currently doesnt have 64. Your installer msi will in any case be 64 bit

http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/64bit-bootstrapper-using-wix-td7582851.html

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add also my finding: I unchecked in a project properties in Build tab a "Prefer 32-bit" and got this error. After re-checking, it was gone. I have Any CPU set as a target.

I am aware that this is not a definite solution, just a symptom-solving, but it might be of help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this error when my solution called a 32 bit dll. In addition to making the platform changes referred to in other replies above, in VS2017 Project {yourproject} Properties Services, I had to change "Use Windows authentication" to "Use Forms authentication"

[image: Services tab is selected, and in the Authentication section "Use Forms authentication" is selected and circled in red]