# Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B, for a MatLab Compiled dll

Tags: c#, matlab, dll

I received a Matlab Compiled .dll (targeted for a 32 bit (x86) system). I use a 64 bit system with Windows 7 on it. I am using Visual Studio IDE for making my application and import this .dll. Below is the Code.

```
[DllImport("Generate_Curve.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, EntryPoint = "Generate_Curve", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
```

I have seen a similar question [.net Framework Error (HRESULT 0x8007000B)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007967/net-framework-error-hresult-0x8007000b) so I tried to change the Platform Target to `x86` or `Any CPU` coupled with `Prefer 32-bit`. Still there is an Error thrown `An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException` with Additional Information as `An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)`. Can any one point out something that I have missed.

Answer (score 0):

I received the answer from Matlab (Mathworks) that there is a bug in Matlab Compiler. If one compiles from a 64 bit Matlab in Matlab Coder for a `target machine or application of 32 bit` the .dll generated is highly likely to be corrupted. The solution is to compile a dll for 32bit target machine/application using a 32 bit Matlab (Matlab Coder). This issue is more of a Matlab Coder issue.