# Running "dotnet --info" gives Unexpected Error: System.BadImageFormatException

Tags: .net, cmd, sdk

I'm trying to get a .Net environment running, but most of my dotnet calls in cmd give me this error message:

**Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (0x8007000B)**

I can't event get **"dotnet --info"** to run without this error. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Most likely, your app has been build for another platform. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18007967/net-framework-error-hresult-0x8007000b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a complete reinstall of everything regarding .NET. So removed runtimes, sdks, etc and even visual studio. That fixed it.