# Could not load file or assembly 'PSCUWebService' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, .net-assembly

While trying to debug a web service, I get the following error: "Could not load file or assembly 'PSCUWebService' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format".  I'm using VS2012 on a 64-bit machine.

I checked the Configuration Manager and the projects have a mixture of platforms (x86, Any CPU, and one has x64).  I changed them to all say 'Any CPU' and that didn't work.

I also checked the Platform target in the properties for the PSCUWebService project and all of its dependencies.  The platform target for PSCUWebService was 'x64' and all of its dependencies had 'Any CPU'.  I changed PSCUWebService to say 'Any CPU', rebuilt, and tried to execute only to receive a different error.

I'm not sure how to go about resolving this.  Considering the research I've done, I'm pretty sure it has to do with the bitness of one of the assemblies.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here's the assembly trace along with the stack trace just in case someone see's something I didn't see:

```
Assembly manager loaded from:  C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\clr.dll
Running under executable  C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\DevServer\11.0\WebDev.WebServer40.exe
--- A detailed error log follows. 

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = PSCUWebService
 (Partial)
WRN: Partial binding information was supplied for an assembly:
WRN: Assembly Name: PSCUWebService | Domain ID: 9
WRN: A partial bind occurs when only part of the assembly display name is provided.
WRN: This might result in the binder loading an incorrect assembly.
WRN: It is recommended to provide a fully specified textual identity for the assembly,
WRN: that consists of the simple name, version, culture, and public key token.
WRN: See whitepaper http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=109270 for more information and common solutions to this issue.
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/Users/cbenoit/workspace/PscuNet/Main/Plugins/PSCUWebService/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\Users\cbenoit\workspace\PscuNet\Main\Plugins\PSCUWebService\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\Users\cbenoit\workspace\PscuNet\Main\Plugins\PSCUWebService\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: 
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Policy not being applied to reference at this time (private, custom, partial, or location-based assembly bind).
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/cbenoit/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/149a454d/99c8d3c8/PSCUWebService.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/cbenoit/AppData/Local/Temp/Temporary ASP.NET Files/root/149a454d/99c8d3c8/PSCUWebService/PSCUWebService.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Users/cbenoit/workspace/PscuNet/Main/Plugins/PSCUWebService/bin/PSCUWebService.DLL.
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x8007000b). Probing terminated.
```

and....

```
[BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'PSCUWebService' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +34
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName assemblyRef, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly reqAssembly, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean forIntrospection, Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +152
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, IntPtr pPrivHostBinder, Boolean forIntrospection) +77
   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String assemblyString, Evidence assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark& stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection) +16
   System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String assemblyString) +28
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +38

[ConfigurationErrorsException: Could not load file or assembly 'PSCUWebService' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssemblyHelper(String assemblyName, Boolean starDirective) +752
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAllAssembliesFromAppDomainBinDirectory() +218
   System.Web.Configuration.CompilationSection.LoadAssembly(AssemblyInfo ai) +130
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetReferencedAssemblies(CompilationSection compConfig) +170
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetPreStartInitMethodsFromReferencedAssemblies() +91
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CallPreStartInitMethods(String preStartInitListPath, Boolean& isRefAssemblyLoaded) +285
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.ExecutePreAppStart() +153
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.Initialize(ApplicationManager appManager, IApplicationHost appHost, IConfigMapPathFactory configMapPathFactory, HostingEnvironmentParameters hostingParameters, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +516

[HttpException (0x80004005): Could not load file or assembly 'PSCUWebService' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +9913572
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +101
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpWorkerRequest wr) +456
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: See if [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539413/using-32-bit-dll-on-64-bit-system-shows-0x8007000b-error) helps.

Comment: Even though you set the Platform Target to Any CPU make sure that "Prefer 32-bit" is not checked.  It is right below the Platform Target on the C# Build Project Settings tab.

Comment: @Jester - I tried your suggestion and was unsuccessful.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @AdamGritt - That check box is grayed out on my project.  Thanks.