# Dotnet Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: .net, asp.net-core

I have this problem with Dotnet and i can't fix it.
When i use this command and it's showing the same error too

```
dotnet new mvc
```

[image: Here it is]

> Unhandled exception. System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load
> file or assembly 'C:\Program Files
> (x86)\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\dotnet.dll'. Format of the executable (.exe)
> or library (.dll) is invalid. File name: 'C:\Program Files
> (x86)\dotnet\sdk\7.0.400\dotnet.dll'

**Here is the error**

[image: Here is the error]

Hope u guys can help me to fix that because i need `dotnet` to finish my project

Comment: sounds like your dotnet installation has become broken somehow; have you tried reinstalling dotnet?

Comment: refer to this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43610551/badimageformatexception-could-not-load-file-or-assembly-or-one-of-its-dependenci), It seems to caused by different version.

Comment: Do not post pictures of text.  Post the text itself.